# how to enable connectiondraining with python boto modify_lb_attribute

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto

I have been trying to enable ELB connection draining using the modify_lb_attribute method in the python boto module; however I haven't been able to get it working. According to the documentation here http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/elb.html I should be able to call it like his:

modify_lb_attribute(load_balancer_name, attribute, value)

Here is an example:

```
modify_lb_attribute('my-elb', 'connectionDraining', 120)
```

When I do this however I receive the following error:

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/ec2/elb/**init**.py", line 421, in modify_lb_attribute
    value.enabled and 'true' or 'false'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'enabled'

I have been able to get it to work successfully with crossZoneLoadBalancing.

For example this works:

```
modify_lb_attribute('my-elb', 'crossZoneLoadBalancing', 'true')
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Working syntax for instantiating a `ConnectionDrainingAttribute` and passing it a to a load balancer:

```
from boto.ec2.elb.attributes import ConnectionDrainingAttribute
import boto.ec2.elb

connection = boto.ec2.elb.connect_to_region("region") 
cda = ConnectionDrainingAttribute(connection)
cda.enabled = True  
cda.timeout = 120
connection.modify_lb_attribute( 
    load_balancer_name='my-elb',
    attribute='connectionDraining',
    value=cda
)
```

More information about the `ConnectionDrainingAttribute` class can be found here in the [boto docs](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/elb.html#boto.ec2.elb.attributes.ConnectionDrainingAttribute).

Answer (score 0):

When you modify the `connectionDraining` attribute of a load balancer, there are actually two values you can supply.  The first is a `boolean` indicating whether you are enabling or disabling the connection draining feature.  The second is an integer indicating the `timeout` which obviously applies only if connection draining is being enabled.

To allow you to specify both of these values, boto defines a `ConnectionDrainingAttribute` class in `boto.ec2.elb.attributes`.  You must pass an instance of this class as the value to `modify_elb_attribute`, e.g.:

```
from boto.ec2.elb.attributes import ConnectionDrainingAttribute

cda = ConnectionDrainingAttribute()
cda.enabled = True
cda.timeout = 120
...
modify_lb_attribute('my-elb', cda)
```

Comment: In the latest version of boto (2.33.0), `boto.ec2.elb.ELBConnection().modify_lb_attribute` requires the attribute name separately from the value:

`ec2_conn.modify_lb_attribute('my-elb', 'ConnectionDraining', cda)`